# Break down dict output into individual keys and save to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble breaking down a df of dict into individual parts based on a key "symbol".

```
def get_positions():
    res = session_auth.my_position()

    df = []
    for item in res['result']:
        data = item['data']
        if data["position_value"] > 0 and data["side"] == "Buy":
            final_dict = {
                "symbol": data['symbol'],
                "position_value": data['position_value'],
                "side": data["side"],
                "realised_pnl" : data["realised_pnl"],
                "unrealised_pnl": data["unrealised_pnl"]
            }
            df.append(final_dict)

    return df
```

I'm using this function to return a df of open positions dict greater than 0 and with side "Buy", but what I would like to do is save the values every minute individually to csv differentiated by "symbol". I would do this using a cron job for the timing.

I'm content to use this code to create my csv but how could I also include the filtered symbol in the title using {symbol}?

```
hdr = False if os.path.isfile(r'/pqth/{symbol} _pos_data.csv') else True
    df.to_csv(r'/path/{symbol}_pos_data.csv', index=False, mode='a', header=hdr)
```

Edit:
Each row of this dict output i would like to breakdown into individual df to then save towards a csv, so I can obtain data every minute.

The output of this function is such:

```
         symbol  position_value side  realised_pnl  unrealised_pnl
0       RSRUSDT       25.912500  Buy     -0.003197       -1.528500
1      MASKUSDT       25.903906  Buy      0.142779       -0.631906
2     OCEANUSDT       25.901200  Buy     -0.003190       -1.378000
3       LTCUSDT       24.732333  Buy      0.374521       -1.860333
4       C98USDT       15.724645  Buy      0.154390        0.124655
5      CELOUSDT       15.577600  Buy     -0.001899       -0.122600
6       ZENUSDT       12.775000  Buy     -0.001909       -0.576000
7        ARUSDT       12.685000  Buy      0.249538        0.009000
8      AAVEUSDT       11.648500  Buy     -0.001223       -0.059700
9      REEFUSDT       10.479103  Buy      0.147024        0.088697
10      FILUSDT       10.387000  Buy     -0.000427       -0.157000
11      ZECUSDT       10.356000  Buy     -0.001366       -0.018500
12     ATOMUSDT       10.148000  Buy     -0.001577       -0.452000
13      MTLUSDT        9.517600  Buy     -0.001138        0.109500
14     STMXUSDT        9.427450  Buy     -0.000594       -0.126400
15      BALUSDT        9.355600  Buy     -0.000961        0.091300
16      GRTUSDT        9.328150  Buy     -0.001255        0.121650
17      RVNUSDT        9.294850  Buy     -0.001124        0.113120
18      RENUSDT        9.291160  Buy     -0.001094        0.088210
19      CVCUSDT        9.288500  Buy     -0.001286       -0.083900
```

From this function I would like to obtain a df of each symbol like such to save into a csv.

```
         symbol  position_value side  realised_pnl  unrealised_pnl
0       RSRUSDT       25.912500  Buy     -0.003197       -1.528500
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're looking for. Your `df` is a list of `dict`s, yes? What is an "open position"? It would be helpful to see an example of the input/output you're hoping for.

Comment: It would be nice to have input examples.
For that purpose, Could you refactor `get_positions()` to `get_positions(position: dict)` ?
And give an example of an input position.
Meaning that you externalize the request to get the position and pass the position to the function.

Comment: Thank you guys, please see above my edits to try to explain further.